# fn <- system.file("extdata", "RD-Mortality-Report_2015-18-180531.pdf", package="dslabs") system("cmd.exe", input = paste("start", fn))

Tags: r

Extract information for the Puerto Rico Hurricane Mortality;
It 10 Questions with sub-questions in some them. This is a practice exercise before exams. Need help under how to code and what functions to use when.

```
fn <- system.file("extdata", "RD-Mortality-Report_2015-18-180531.pdf", package="dslabs")
system("cmd.exe", input = paste("start", fn))
download.file("fn", 
              "RD-Mortality-Report_2015-18-180531.pdf")
pdftools::pdf_text('RD-Mortality-Report_2015-18-180531.pdf') 

library(tidyverse)
library(pdftools)
options(digits = 3)    # report 3 significant digits

> pdftools::pdf_text('RD-Mortality-Report_2015-18-180531.pdf')                         
Error in normalizePath(path.expand(path), winslash, mustWork) : 
  path[1]="RD-Mortality-Report_2015-18-180531.pdf": The system cannot find the file specified
```

Need assistance on how to structure my code and understand the errors.
The above error is from Question 2 which I have attempted.

Comment: Question 2: We are going to create a tidy dataset with each row representing one observation. The variables in this dataset will be year, month, day and deaths.

Use the pdftools package to read in fn using the pdf_text function. Store the results in an object called txt.

Describe what you see in txt.

Comment: a)A table with the mortality data. 
b)A character string of length 12. Each entry represents the text in each page. The mortality data is in there somewhere.
c)A character string with one entry containing all the information in the PDF file.
d)An html document.                                                                                                                  #Which one of the above is correct?#

Comment: @Mat Can you help with the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works perfectly for me

```r
download.file("https://github.com/c2-d2/pr_mort_official/raw/master/data/RD-Mortality-Report_2015-18-180531.pdf", "testfile.pdf")
pdftools::pdf_text("testfile.pdf")
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199112/discussion-on-answer-by-user5783745-fn-system-fileextdata-rd-mortality-r).