# Define s to be the first entry of the x object

Tags: r, rstudio

How many entries does s have?

[fn <- system.file("extdata", "RD-Mortality-Report_2015-18-180531.pdf", package="dslabs") system("cmd.exe", input = paste("start", fn))](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57832387/fn-system-fileextdata-rd-mortality-report-2015-18-180531-pdf-package)

```
download.file("https://github.com/c2- 
d2/pr_mort_official/raw/master/data/RD-Mortality-Report_2015-18- 
180531.pdf", "testfile.pdf")
pdftools::pdf_text("testfile.pdf")
mypdf <- pdftools::pdf_text("testfile.pdf")
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
mypdf[9] %>% str_split("\n")
```

Assistance with code and explains the code used. Beginner level of R

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199153/discussion-on-question-by-coogan-pillay-define-s-to-be-the-first-entry-of-the-x).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use `lengths` to get the get. the `length` of each of the `list` elements after the `split`.  As we are only doing the `split` on a single element, the output would also be a `list` of length 1

```
library(stringr)
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
l1 <- mypdf[9] %>% 
         str_split("\n") %>% 
         lengths
```

The second part is to apply the `str_trim` on the `list` elements after the split and then get the first character (`substring` can be used here)

```
out <- mypdf[9] %>% 
           str_split("\n") %>% 
           map(~ str_trim(.x) %>% 
                   first %>%
                   substring(nchar(.) ))
out[[1]]
#[1] "s"
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199156/discussion-on-answer-by-akrun-define-s-to-be-the-first-entry-of-the-x-object).